# making a python game as a stand alone application

Tags: python, pygame

recently I am studying making using python. I even made a small game. I wanted my friend to play it. But he did not have python so he had to download python and other related modules to run the game.
So I wanted to ask is there a way to convert the whole game in a stand-alone application or make an exe file of it.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this by making binary file of your .py file using pyinstaller.

https://pyinstaller.readthedocs.io/en/stable/

`pip install pyinstaller`
`pyinstaller -F file.py`

Comment: Thanks for the advice. Can you also suggest me how to convert the game to an apk file? Again thanks in advance.